# how to compile a 64-bit .dll on windows with lcc-win?

Tags: c, dll, java-native-interface, 64-bit, lcc-win32

Using Windows 7 64-bit and lcc-win32

2 source files:

```
Hello.c
HelloImpl.c
```

The following:

```
lcc -shadows -unused -v -IC:\lcc\include -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\include\win32" -g2 %1.c
lcc -shadows -unused -v -IC:\lcc\include -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\include\win32" -g2 %1Impl.c
lcclnk.exe -map %1.map -dll -o %1.dll %1.obj %1Impl.obj
```

Produces a 32-bit .dll

but this:

```
lcc64 -shadows -unused -v -IC:\lcc\include64 -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\include\win32" -g2 %1.c
lcc64 -shadows -unused -v -IC:\lcc\include64 -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\include\win32" -g2 %1Impl.c
lcclnk64.exe -map %1.map -dll -o %1.dll %1.obj %1Impl.obj
```

Produces:

```
Entry point DllMain not found
Use the -entry command line option
```

After the linker command and a 2K .dll filled with zeros !

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not.
I'm using Visual Studio 2013, which has its own problems
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724029/windows-xp-and-windows-server-2003-support-in-visual-studio-2013/21761080#21761080