# Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 support in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

How about Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 support in Visual Studio 2013? Can i write programs in C++ for these systems in Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the retail edition of VS2013: yes, no problem.  Project + Properties, General, Platform Toolset = v120_xp.

Comment: Hans, do you happen to know what the command line equivalent to _USING_V110_SDK71_ is in the new toolset?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927544/using-v110-sdk71-equivalent-for-vs2013