# WindowsForm Application fails to run on different computer

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, windows-xp-sp2

I'm very new to VB programming. I've made an application on VB using Visual Basic 2013 Ultimate and want it to run on Windows XP installed on my office PC.

The application does convert a delimited text file into an excel file using text to column property of excel.

I've done proper targeting of .Net Framework (3.5) and compiled on proper CPU type (x86). My PC has Office 2013. The application runs fine on my PC (Windows 8.1 x64). I copied the executable file testExcel.exe from the debug directory to any location of my PC and it worked like a charm. However this is not working on another PC having Windows 7.

The error it shows is `testExcel has stopped working` after execution.

The other PC has Office 2010 and .Net framework (4.5) installed.

Can anyone advise what I am missing here? Is this a problem related to the excel library imported while coding in my PC?
For example, I have imported below libraries after I added reference into my Project for **Microsoft

```
Excel 15.0 Object Library:

Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Imports System.IO
```

If yes, then what is the workaround?
Please note that I have made a very basic application and tried to run in different PCs and it worked on those PCs.
Please suggest me everything I need to care about to make this run on Windows XP machine.
Sorry for my English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: while compiling select any cpu and then check

Comment: Have you set the `Copy Local` property of your `Microsoft.Office.Interop` references to `True`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What does "this is not even working" mean exactly? What is the **exact problem** you're having? Do you get an error message? If so, what is the **specific** message you're getting? You have that information right in front of you; there is absolutely no reason you can't provide it to us in your question. We can't read your screen from where we're sitting. Please [edit] your question to explain what "not even working" means.

Comment: @Terror.Blade: I tried what you advised. That is how I made a very application work on XP.

Comment: is excel is installed in all pcs?

Comment: @KenWhite: Sorry for my english. I edited. The error it shows is "test.exe has stopped working" on Windows 7 as well as XP.

Comment: @Terror.Blade: Yes, it is installed. But it is 2010 version. While my PC has 2013 version.
Thanks

Comment: That problem has nothing to do with Excel. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19724029/62576

Comment: @TroyCarlson: It made sense and I tried the same. But the error is same again. Do I need to create a setup for this?