# _using_v110_sdk71_ equivalent for VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio

To target XP in VS2012 in the command line, we used _USING_V110_SDK71_. What is the equivalent for VS2013 and toolset v120_xp?

Comment: Why not just set those options in a VS project and check the command line.

Comment: It appears to be the same:   /D "_USING_V110_SDK71_"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not the way it worked.  Back in VS2012, you used the Project + Properties, General, Platform Toolset setting and selected `v110_xp`.  Which made *several* setting changes.  As a **side-effect**, you'd also get the _USING_V110_SDK71_ macro defined.  Which is accurate, one of the setting changes is that you'll use the SDK version 7.1 headers and libraries instead of version 8.  7.1 is the last SDK version that's still compatible with XP.

Which isn't actually important for anything, by far the most important change that you got was the linker's System, Minimum Required Version setting.  Using v110_xp ensured that this setting was changed to 5.01, the XP version number.  Without it you target 6.00, the Vista version number.  It is a very important setting, Windows pays attention to it and turns off several appcompat shims when you tell it that you designed your program to run well on the latest Windows versions.

It still works the same in VS2013.  Select the `v120_xp` toolset.

Comment: So on the command line, _USING_V110_SDK71_ is not really the key, but rather linking to the 7.1 headers and libraries. For a dll, is there something I need to do re: minimum require version setting? I know that in Console and Windows apps there is a 5.01 setting, but how about a library?