# Executable Valid on Win7 and On WinXP professional SP3 "not a valid Win32 application (193)"

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, executable, access-denied

I have an executable compiled by MSVS2013 on Windows 7 SP1 32 bit with C runtime statically linked and platform toolset "Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)"

It runs perfectly on Win7 (see attached screenshot of Dependency Walker profiling).

[image]

It fails to run on WinXP:

[image]

Here is the profile log:

```
Starting profile on 12/9/2014 at 2:55:03 AM

Operating System: Microsoft Windows XP Professional (32-bit), version 5.01.2600 Service Pack 3
Program Executable: c:\temp\OCTOPUS.EXE
Program Arguments: 
Starting Directory: C:\Temp\
Search Path: C:\Program Files\ActiveState Komodo Edit 8\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009b\runtime\win32;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009b\bin;C:\VisaPoint\sbperl\perl\bin

Options Selected:
     Simulate ShellExecute by inserting any App Paths directories into the PATH environment variable.
     Log DllMain calls for process attach and process detach messages.
     Log DllMain calls for all other messages, including thread attach and thread detach.
     Hook the process to gather more detailed dependency information.
     Log LoadLibrary function calls.
     Log GetProcAddress function calls.
     Log thread information.
     Use simple thread numbers instead of actual thread IDs.
     Log first chance exceptions.
     Log debug output messages.
     Use full paths when logging file names.
     Log a time stamp with each line of log.
     Automatically open and profile child processes.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

00:00:00.000: Failure starting the process. %1 is not a valid Win32 application (193).


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m82n6.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yr37.png
```

Comment: What CPU is in the machine it fails on? VS2013 default settings produce executables that won't run on some AMD processors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 support in Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724029/windows-xp-and-windows-server-2003-support-in-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 1):

Modern versions of Visual Studio, starting with VS2012, use linker settings that marks the executable image compatible with the current generation of Windows.  Version 6, started with Vista.  XP and Server2003 were in the previous generation, version 5.

You can still build programs that run on XP with VS2013.  But you have to make a setting change.  Right-click the project, Properties, General.  Change the Platform Toolset setting to `v120_xp`.

There are a few consequences, your program gets built with an old version of the Windows SDK.  V7.1, the last one that was still compatible with XP.  The C runtime library makes a bunch of operating system calls that are only available in generation 6.  It will stumble along without them, affecting relatively minor details related to threading and culture.  This is the kind of FUD that ought to remind you that it might not be the best idea to still promise support for such an ancient operating system.  Make sure you keep a running version of XP around so you can properly test and repro.  And keep in mind that you can't install VS on it anymore so if you do get a support call from an XP user then you tend to get a fairly heavy migraine.

Comment: Maybe this is irrelevant. But one can also change the subystem after file has been compiled by changing whatever version it is set to, to the older one, in hex editor. For example to run executables marked for usual Windows Vista+ compatibility on Windows XP I used to change second `06 00 00` binary entry in PE header (usually it is second in the entire file too) to `05 00 00`.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, just forgot to set SUBSYSTEM in Linker options. 
Here is a link with explanations:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/linking-applications-using-visual-studio-2012-to-run-on-windows-xp

Comment: You cannot link a binary without setting the SUBSYSTEM. You didn't *forget* to set the SUBSYSTEM; you used an inappropriate one. This is explained in [Hans Passant's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27379460/1889329).

Comment: I forget to set SUBSYSTEM to 5.01 to enable WINXp compatibility. If SUBSYSTEM is not set in VisualStudio 2013, platform toolset setting does not have effect. Actually, VS2013 after Upgrade 4 started to emit warning about unset SYSTEM setting in Linker if platform  toolset is set in C++.